# How to know if someone joined/left a stage channel in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there an event for when a user joins or leave a stage channel in discord.js?

I couldn't find any information on this online

I tried the `guildAuditLogEntryCreate` and `voiceStateUpdate` events but they will not fire when a user joins or leaves a stage channel.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using the `voiceStateUpdate` event, make sure you have the `GuildVoiceStates` intent enabled. Note this event also fires for normal voice channel events as well, so be sure to filter for only stage events later on.

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: ["Guilds", "GuildVoiceStates"]
});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (before, after) => {
  const { member } = before;
  const left = before.channelId && !after.channelId;
  const channel = left ? before.channel : after.channel;

  console.log(`${member.user.tag} ${left ? 'left' : 'joined'} ${channel.name}`);
})
```